# Typeorm config in next js

Tags: orm, next.js, typeorm

I spent some days configuring typeorm (postgresql) for Next JS but i didn't succeed.
Most tutorials explain how to use prisma with Next JS.

here are the steps I have taken:

1. I installed `pg, reflect-metadata, @types/react, @types/node, typeorm`
2. I generated the typeorm files using `npx typeorm init`
3. I edited the ormconfig.js

How to create a typeorm connection and use it in next js ?
any good tutorial about using typeorm in next.js ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use prisma ORM. it will work properly with next js, vercel PostgreSQL and PostgreSQL also.
you can check prisma documentation for more info.